# How to rename AWS RDS parameter group from the AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to rename my RDS parameter group, is it possible to do this from the AWS Console?

Comment: I don't see a way to rename them, but you may add a new group with the name you want, then delete the old one.  Maybe someone else will give you a better answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've changed several parameters in the original group and I don't want to go through the list again. I just want another name for the group.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it indirectly by creating a group copy with the new name.

Select group > Parameter group actions > Copy > New DB parameter group identifier

Comment: This is indeed the only way, but note that changing the parameter group for an instance, even if the new group is an exact copy, will almost certainly require a reboot of the database instance.